# Format function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to have the result of this function in SQL Server 2012:

```
select FORMAT(256,'0000000#')
```

Edit: sorry I mean SQL Server version 10 (2012)

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: @GaganSharma To Have the result for '256', '00000256' and for '1200', '00001200'

Comment: If you took the time to try it in SQL Server you would find that that is exactly what it does. Whats the actual problem here?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there is no Format function in sql server 2010 and i need the result of that function in there

Comment: There is no sql server 2010 either. You should probably give us a clue and tell us which version you're on.

Comment: SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @amit I guess  so

Comment: Don't guess. You need to find a different career (like astrology) if you just guess. Take the very basic action of using google to work out how to 100% verify what version you have.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the RIGHT function or REPLICATE. Suppose you want to have 8 character string.

```
DECLARE @value INT = 256

--EXAMPLE WITH RIGHT FUNCTION
select RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@value), 8)

--EXAMPLE WITH REPLICATE FUNCTION    
select REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@value)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is data formation which you should do in your presentation layer. If there is no option, try this as well

```
DECLARE @VALUE INT = 256
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(STR(@VALUE),' ','0'),8) as formatted_value
```